# MySQL Clear connection status

Tags: mysql, performance, connection

Two processes are sharing the same MySQL connection (to save the re-connection overhead). They  use the connection one after the other, i.e. one process never use the connection when the other process is currently using it.

There is a problem with this: sometimes process A leaves the connection with pending transactions, or with some tables being locked, temp tables... and when process B gets the connection it doesn't know (and doesn't want to know) it has to deal with this "history".

What I'd like to do is clear the connection just before it is given to a process. I.e. clear all current data linked to the connection usage done by the other process just before.

Some posts recommend to do (using an API), while I'd prefer to use a MySQL command (query-like) if possible (similar to `FLUSH` or `RESET`, but that would do what I need)

```
  mysql_change_user(connection, user, password[, db])
```

**Questions**

- Is there a better way to clear the connection?
- Is doing a "change user" still better than
  creating a new connection (performance wise) ?